# Localstack lambda is not triggered by SQS

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, localstack

I'm trying to use [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) to test a lambda triggered by an SQS event.

Here it is my `localstack` `docker-compose`:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:53:53"
      - "127.0.0.1:53:53/udp"
      - "127.0.0.1:443:443"
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"
      - "127.0.0.1:4571:4571"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=${SERVICES- }
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR- }
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker
      - LAMBDA_REMOTE_DOCKER=false
      - LOCALSTACK_API_KEY=${LOCALSTACK_API_KEY- }
      - KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY=${KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY- }
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - HOST_TMP_FOLDER=${TMPDIR}
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

And here is my python lambda code in the `handler.py` file:

```
import json
import logging
import os

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def handler(event, context):
    try:
        logger.info(f"### ENV VARS {os.environ}")
        logger.info(f"### EVENT {event}")
        logger.info(f"### ENV VARS {context}")

        if event and "Records" in event:
            for elt in event["Records"]:
                logger.info(elt["body"])
        
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
        raise e
```

Here it is the lambda `Dockerfile`
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

```
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN pip install -r ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/requirements.txt --quiet

COPY src/ ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

CMD ["handler.handler"]
```

I run the following commands to create the lambda and the event

`aws --endpoint http://localhost:4566 sqs create-queue --queue-name TEST_QUEUE`

`aws --endpoint http://localhost:4566 lambda create-function --timeout 120 --function-name python-lambda-test --handler handler.handler --code ImageUri=python-lambda-test:latest --role arn:aws:iam::000000000:role/lambda-ex`

`aws --endpoint http://localhost:4566 lambda create-event-source-mapping --function-name python-lambda-test --batch-size 1 --event-source-arn arn:aws:sqs:sa-east-1:000000000000:TEST_QUEUE`

And finally, this command to test the Lambda function

`aws --endpoint http://localhost:4566 sqs send-message --queue-url  http://localhost:4566/000000000000/TEST_QUEUE --message-body 'this is a message'`

But all this without success
I'm receiving this message in the logs

```
2021-08-30 18:30:23,439:API: 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2021 18:30:23] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2021-08-30T18:30:23:DEBUG:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_api: Found 1 source mappings for event from SQS queue arn:aws:sqs:sa-east-1:000000000000:TEST_QUEUE: ['arn:aws:lambda:sa-east-1:000000000000:function:python-lambda-test']

2021-08-30T18:30:23:DEBUG:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_api: Starting SQS message polling thread for Lambda API

2021-08-30 18:30:23,467:API: 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2021 18:30:23] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2021-08-30 18:30:23,520:API: 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2021 18:30:23] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2021-08-30T18:30:23:DEBUG:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_api: Sending event from event source arn:aws:sqs:sa-east-1:000000000000:TEST_QUEUE to Lambda arn:aws:lambda:sa-east-1:000000000000:function:python-lambda-test

2021-08-30T18:30:23:DEBUG:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_executors: Lambda executed in Event (asynchronous) mode, no response will be returned to caller

2021-08-30T18:30:23:INFO:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_executors: Determined main container target IP: 172.17.0.2

2021-08-30T18:30:23:INFO:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_executors: Running lambda: arn:aws:lambda:sa-east-1:000000000000:function:python-lambda-test

2021-08-30T18:30:23:DEBUG:localstack.utils.docker: Running container with image: lambci/lambda:

2021-08-30T18:30:23:DEBUG:localstack.utils.docker: Creating container with image: lambci/lambda:

2021-08-30T18:30:23:DEBUG:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_executors: Lambda arn:aws:lambda:sa-east-1:000000000000:function:python-lambda-test result / log output:


>

2021-08-30 18:30:23,635:API: 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2021 18:30:23] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2021-08-30 18:30:23,658:API: 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2021 18:30:23] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2021-08-30 18:30:23,677:API: 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2021 18:30:23] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2021-08-30 18:30:23,701:API: 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2021 18:30:23] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2021-08-30 18:30:23,734:API: 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2021 18:30:23] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2021-08-30 18:30:23,754:API: 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2021 18:30:23] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2021-08-30T18:30:23:INFO:localstack.utils.run: Thread run method <function LambdaExecutor.execute.<locals>.do_execute at 0x7f69de3770e0>(None) failed: Lambda process returned with error. Result: . Output:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 268, in _raise_for_status

response.raise_for_status()

File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 943, in raise_for_status

raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)

requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.41/containers/create


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/docker.py", line 1230, in create_container

container = create_container()

File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/docker.py", line 1226, in create_container

**kwargs,

File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py", line 870, in create

resp = self.client.api.create_container(**create_kwargs)

File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 430, in create_container

return self.create_container_from_config(config, name)

File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 441, in create_container_from_config

return self._result(res, True)

File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 274, in _result

self._raise_for_status(response)

File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 270, in _raise_for_status

raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)

File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception

raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)

docker.errors.APIError: 400 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/containers/create: Bad Request ("invalid reference format")


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 336, in run_lambda_executor

func_details, env_vars, command, docker_flags=docker_flags, stdin=event_stdin_bytes

File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 815, in execute_in_container

stdin=stdin,

File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/docker.py", line 1280, in run_container

additional_flags=additional_flags,

File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/docker.py", line 1238, in create_container

raise ContainerException()

localstack.utils.docker.ContainerException



The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:


Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/run.py", line 138, in run

result = self.func(self.params, **kwargs)

File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 247, in do_execute

return _run(func_arn=func_arn)

File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cloudwatch/cloudwatch_util.py", line 157, in wrapped

raise e

File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cloudwatch/cloudwatch_util.py", line 153, in wrapped

result = func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 234, in _run

raise e

File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 220, in _run

result = self._execute(func_arn, func_details, event, context, version)

File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 450, in _execute

event=stdin, env_vars=environment, func_details=func_details, docker_flags=docker_flags

File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 375, in run_lambda_executor

) from error

localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_executors.InvocationException: Lambda process returned with error. Result: . Output:
```

What is my mistake in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is in the free version localstack does not support custom images

Comment: Any resolution here?

Comment: Has this issue been resolved yet? @RenatoRamosNascimento